# Explicitly timeout file read I/O operation in php in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, io

I have production script that copies and renames files from one mounted network share to another (both CIFS), and sometimes the `copy` function hangs indefinitely on read I/O dropping the process into uninterruptible sleep where it can only be killed with `SIGKILL.` (Thankfully, TASK_KILLABLE, apparently.)

Since operation is blocked at the `copy` call I can't gracefully handle the I/O failure, nor, more importantly, log it.

```
$res = copy("/path/to/mount/file.pdf", "/path/to/productionqueue/newfile.pdf");

//This doesn't run because of the process state.
if($res) {
  //Report success to the log.
} else {
  //Report failure to the log.
}
```

It's an environment, file-specific issue, and manual intervention can fix it, but I need to log the failure so an administrator can be notified about the condition. (Aside: I think it's a lock race condition. I can fix the problem by unmounting and remounting the source share, but reproducing it is a bit of an issue.)

Ideally, I'd like the `copy` call to timeout after 10 seconds, so I can log the error, but there doesn't seem to be a way in PHP to do that.

What I'm considering is delegating copy or read operations to a subprocess monitored by the `timeout` command and responding based on the exit codes, but is there a simpler way in a PHP script to handle this sort of scenario?

Everything I've found in my search suggests there's only runtime configuration available for socket/network timeouts, not filesystem calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no as far as I can tell - there's no built in way to timeout a file read operation in PHP. However, on systems where your I/O is `TASK_KILLABLE` you can do the I/O operation in a subprocess and use `timeout -s 9` to terminate it. `timeout` can will then return an exit status that is non-zero.

For example, with the `cp` utility:

```
$ssrc = escapeshellarg($src);
$sdst = escapeshellarg($dst);
//10 second timeout, send KILL
exec("timeout -s 9 10 cp $ssrc $sdst 2>&1", $output, $ret);
if($ret != 0) {
  log("Failed copying $src to $dst, exit status: $ret");
}
```